# Material Component Library version 1.1.0 not working

Tags: android, material-components-android

I want to use the startIconDrawable feature that is present in the material component library version 1.1.0. But when I upgrade from version 1.0.0 to version 1.1.0, the outlined box disappears and the activity crashes. Please Help

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:hint="Username"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Log after clicking the button

```
     2020-06-04 21:09:55.873 5024-5024/com.example.digidocsbeta E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.digidocsbeta, PID: 5024
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.digidocsbeta/com.example.digidocsbeta.Login}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53 in com.example.digidocsbeta:layout/activity_login: Binary XML file line #53 in com.example.digidocsbeta:layout/activity_login: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3448)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53 in com.example.digidocsbeta:layout/activity_login: Binary XML file line #53 in com.example.digidocsbeta:layout/activity_login: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53 in com.example.digidocsbeta:layout/activity_login: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:854)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1006)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.example.digidocsbeta.Login.onCreate(Login.java:12)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7955)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7944)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3423)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068)
2020-06-04 21:09:55.874 5024-5024/com.example.digidocsbeta E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:248)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkMaterialTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:222)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:150)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainTintedStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:120)
        at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:424)
        at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:396)
            ... 30 more
2020-06-04 21:09:55.895 5024-5024/com.example.digidocsbeta I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5024 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Add your layout, code and the stacktrace

Comment: Hi Welcome to stack overflow please read [how-to-ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have updated the question @GabrieleMariotti

Comment: I have updated the question @PraveenSP

Comment: Activity Crashes...What is error message ? could you update your question with stack trace ?

Comment: @PraveenSP added

Comment: and this error goes away when I use version  1.0.0 but I want to use version 1.1.0, so that I can use app:startIconDrawable feature

Comment: Make sure your app theme is having material theme as parent

Comment: The issue is here: `The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents`. Your app theme should inherit from a [Material Components theme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#material-components-themes).